# Ubuntu stopping to work aleatory

Tags: drivers, nvidia, freeze, syslog, mutter

Everyone. 
English isn't my first language (I told you before read rs) 
I'm experiencing aleatory freezing on my Ubuntu. I haven't noted if it happen in a specific situation. Bellow there are two images showing what I named freeze. It is, I've saw two mouse pointers and than, lock, crash, freeze.... I can't do nothing, only restart at power button :( 
I just already had reinstall Ubuntu thinking it could solve my problem, but no. It continuous happening in a fresh install. I don't have sure how can I ask for help. i.e. what files (log's) should I providing or something like that...
During one of crashes I got error in syslog, kern log and /var/crash/

[image: lock 1]
[image: lock 2]
[kern-log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HftvHSnelIgsMtlu1P6r8apY67OhEVdJ/view?usp=sharing)
[syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1odqULdnrK2BEeRCtGdvC1fTW-3fVWDyn/view?usp=sharing)
[log crash](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbcTYryGQRJWkkuwCzcFhNOAEdKFlCKg/view?usp=sharing)
[log crash _usr_bin_nvidia-persistenced](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l_zwPEIuUXF-q64emYrFWORrtdwoOYa_/view?usp=sharing)
[dmesg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WbxMXhoa-oupARfx5NDF6_7lZSozKNBu/view?usp=sharing)
[lspci -vvv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1elYmR5g78vr5S2oo7rY_Lk0Ks_XeUKiW/view?usp=sharing)
[journalctl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15kGE4aVdUgB2u1Z_kLePHCDSX9KrJbS6/view?usp=sharing)
[nvidia bug report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12vMYrNxfh-ghLrGIHEJPUhLaGKjVT3rx/view?usp=sharing)

Hardware
XPS L502x
CPU: Intel i7 2ª gen
Memory: 8GB
Hd: ssd 240gb
VGA1: Intel 
VGA2: Nvidia 525M

PS.: I've noted two permission error in nvidia persistence (envion an map). I don't know what it means.

Can anyone suggest some?

Comment: Anyone? I countinuous having the same problem in 20.04 and driver nvidia 390.132 :'(

Comment: Have you tried to install different desktop environment: `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` or something else? Also try creating new user. Maybe some user's config files are the cause of this behavior. CTRL+ALT+F3 will switch you to terminal text session, where you could login and install new desktop environment or create new user.

Comment: I'll try to install a new DM (Lubuntu)... I'll to post information as soon as possible. Thak your for suggest :D

Comment: @Gryu, I tryed with Lubuntu and Xubuntu DM, but the result was the same. System crash aleatory and in this DMs I saw a tipe of color BUGs in external monitor (I don't know how to describe this in English). See the photos for both DM.
Lubuntu - [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ToyDoF7wcvYLkPQT6)
Xubuntu - [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/vM7EUaPddR7nQXC88)